# Is there anything equivalent to `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit` for bottom nav component?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack

`setOffscreenPageLimit` is an easy and nice way of keeping few fragments alive in the viewpager if you would like to cache their data. Is there a similar concept for Bottom Navigation being used with NavComponent?

The problem is that I would like to cache my views so that on every navigation change the fragment doesn't get recreated. I do use Viewmodels but since my fragment gets recreated it will set the adapter on the new view and user will see the loading.

Comment: AFAIK no, you have to set up your BottomNavigationView with a ViewPager, after that you can do that see https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/